# Functions within object literal notation in TypeScript. Why `this` context is of type `any`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Perhaps the question was already asked, but I could not find any. And it seems so naive. TypeScript comes well with object literal notation, but when defining the methods within, than it can't properly handle `this` context inside that functions, it seems `this` receives `any` type, so there is no auto-completion.

```
var foo = {
    log(str) {
        console.log(str);
    },
    print(str) {
        this. /* No autocompletion */
    }
};    
foo. /* Normal autocompletion */
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20log(str)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(str)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20print(str)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%20%2F*%20No%20autocompletion%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A#src=var%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20log(str)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(str)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20print(str)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.%20%2F*%20No%20autocompletion%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo.%20%2F*%20Normal%20autocompletion%20*%2F%0D%0A)

Naturally, I would expect that the autocompletion properly works in method, the same way it does when consuming `foo` variable. I could declare a class first, then instantiate the object, but why it doesn't work without declaring intermediate `class` or `interface`, in this simple case it seems like a boilerplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official [TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) on functions:

> [...] is still `any`. That’s because `this` comes from the function expression inside the object literal.

The [TypeScript Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) on GitHub also has good explanations about the `this` keyword and its context.

Comment: Thanks, indeed, we have better to declare a class for this, then we have all in one place. Otherwise, we have a lot of repeated code, interface definition and the declaration, and we have then two places to maintain. So, that means for me, that object literal notations are not quite usable.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:
Since TS@2.3, this behaviour is a little bit more complicated:

- If the method has an explicitly declared this parameter, this has the type of that parameter.
- Otherwise, if the method is contextually typed by a signature with a
  this parameter, this has the type of that parameter.
- Otherwise, if --noImplicitThis is enabled and the containing object
  literal has a contextual type that includes a ThisType, this has
  type T.
- Otherwise, if --noImplicitThis is enabled and the containing object
  literal has a contextual type that doesn't include a ThisType,
  this has the contextual type.
- Otherwise, if --noImplicitThis is enabled this has the type of the
  containing object literal.
- Otherwise, this has type any.

[reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14141)